# Set map marker title from array

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, google-maps-markers

I am trying to create map markers from an array by using geocoding. I store the addresses on an array as well as the addresses' title. problem is in my loop, the title is being set to the last value of my last array although the markers are being set correctly from the addresses in the array. here is my code:

```
maprender : function (comp, map) {
  new google.maps.Marker({
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(this._geo.getLatitude(), this._geo.getLongitude()),
    map: map
  });

  var names = new Array("ABC","DEF","GHI"),
      mapAdd = new Array();

  mapAdd[0] = "Address 1";
  mapAdd[1] = "Address 2";
  mapAdd[2] = "Address 3";

  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder(); 

  for (var i = 0; i < mapAdd.length; i++) {
    var lat = 0,
        lng = 0,
        x = names[i];

    geocoder.geocode({
      'address': mapAdd[i]}, 
      function (results,status) {
        if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
          lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();

          console.log(lat + " " + lng);
          new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
            title: x,
            map: map
          });
          console.log(x);
        }
      }
    });

  }

}
```

the title is returning "GHI" on all of the markers.

Comment: http://blog.jbrantly.com/2010/04/creating-javascript-function-inside.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on http://blog.jbrantly.com/2010/04/creating-javascript-function-inside.html

Try it this way

```
function geocode(i) {

  var lat = 0,
      lng = 0,
      x = names[i];

  geocoder.geocode({
    'address': mapAdd[i]},
    function (results,status) {
      if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
        lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();

        console.log(lat + " " + lng);
        new google.maps.Marker({
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
          title: x,
          map: map
        });
        console.log(x);
      }
    }
  });

}

for (var i = 0; i < mapAdd.length; i++) {
  geocode(i);
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you as I've read the blog, It seems that functions inside a loop are created only once. I'll get back when I get a solution and try you code.

Comment: My problem is I do not know where to place the function Im creating in Sencha. I tried placing it in my view and controller but it says function not defined.

Comment: Place the code above in mapRender() OR place the geocode() function in your view but then you need to call this.geocode(i) then

Comment: It depends where you want you function to be places. If you it to belong to the view then yes, put it after (or before) mapRender. OR you can also put it within mapRender. In this case you just need to paste the code from my answer in mapRender

Comment: putting it in the view and using this.geocode(i) is working for me. but i cannot access my arrays. would you mind if I ask how i can access the variables from my function

Comment: You can either define your arrays in the geocode function or, if your really need them to be defined within the mapRender function, define them as attributes of your view. So define this.names = ['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI'] in the mapRender function and then you can access them in the geocode function with this.names.

Comment: Okay, I can now access the arrays I set in my view and I can get and set the values of it in the initialize of my view. But the weird thing is I cannot access the arrays in my mapRender listener. It is saying "cannot set property '0' on undefined". I find it weird because the initialize function happens first before the mapRender. Any suggestion?

Comment: I've got it working now. The problem was I was setting the values of my arrays in the initialize function of my view. But now I made a loop inside the mapRender function to set the values of the arrays. Thanks for helping out. Appreciate it.